# Vue 3 migrate key per component in template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

On vue 2 for place two components side by side in template need be set key per component AND key should be difference (example apply string concat with prefix)

[image]

vue 2 work variant

```
<template v-for="i in items">
                    <trigger   :key="'track_' +i.id" />
                    <otherComp :key="i.id" ></otherComp>
    </template>
```

**Now in vue 3 the situation is reversed :D**

[image]

How can i set difference key like in vue 2 now ?

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, you have to place the key on the template tag.

```
<template v-for="i in items" :key="i.id">
  <trigger />
  <otherComp />
</template>
```

If for whatever reason you have to add a key on the other components you can do it.

Comment: i need different key per component how in vue 2:  trigger id=1 otherComp id= 'prefix_1'. If i set key both in template and component i get error

Comment: Why do you need your components to have a key?

Comment: For example, check the following link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-glitter-uhzug?file=/src/App.vue

As you can see, no need to add a key on the components wrapped on the template tag with v-for

Comment: I also ran into the same problem. One template tag, has two children with each requires different keys.

Comment: What do you try to achieve by having separate keys for each component? If you show an example it might be easier to help